# How to build multi tenant application using docker

Tags: nginx, docker, multi-tenant

I am pretty much new to the docker concept and know basics of it. 
I just wanted to know how can we build multi tenant application using docker. 
Where the containers will use the local hosted database with different schema.With the nginx we can do reverse proxy but how we can achieve it?
because every container will be accessed by `localhost:8080` and how we can add upstream and server part. 
It will be very helpful if some one explains it to me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want processes in containers to connect to resources on the host.

From you containers perspective in bridge mode (the default), the host's IP is the gateway. Unfortunate the gateway IP address may vary and can only be determinate at runtime.

Here are a few ways to get it:

- From the host using docker inspect: `docker inspect <container name or ID>`. The gateway will be available under `NetworkSettings.Networks.Gateway`.
- From the container you can execute `route | awk '/^default/ { print $2 }'`

One other possibility is to use `--net=host` when running your container.
This will run you processes on the same network as your processes on your host. Doing so will make your database accessible from the container on `localhost`.

Note that using `--net=host` will not work on Docker for mac/windows.

Comment: It's not necessary to use the host's IP.  The docker0 interface address (usually 172.17.0.1) would work if the DB is set to listen on both localhost and docker0 interfaces, or all interfaces (not recommended for security reasons).